# Magento 2 - InstallData script doesn´t add column to my 'customer_entitiy'

Tags: magento2, customer, custom, customer-attribute, customer-address

I´m now trying to add a custom attribute for like 5 hours now. It drives me nuts that I dont find the solution hope you can help me.

I want a custom attribute to be displayed and saved when the user wants to register in the frontend.

What I did :

1. Create Module

**module.xml** -> *app/code/Magento/CustomerAttribute/etc*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_CustomerAttribute"  setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

2. Create InstallData.php with my custom value

**InstallData.php** -> *app/code/Magento/CustomerAttribute/Setup*

```
<?php

namespace Magento\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'kndnumber', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Kunden nummer',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'kndnumber')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

After running ***php bin/magento setup:upgrade*** nothing happens the field was not added to the table *customer_entitiy*. 
[image: phpmyadmin]

I tryed every tutorial on the Internet and still cant get it working. If I could debug that thing it would be a bit easier for developers.

Do you have any suggestions why this script doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer is an EAV entity which means an attribute is not added to the main table. There should be an entry in `eav_attribute` with `attribute_code` set to `kndnumber`. Values for this attribute will be saved in `customer_entity_varchar` table.

If you do not see the attribute in the `eav_attribute` table make sure your module is enabled. You can also remove entry from `module_setup` table and run installation process once again. Remember that `InstallData` script will only fire once if there is no entry in `setup_module` table.

Comment: Ok never came across an EAV entity, thanks for the explanation but I still can´t see "kndnumber" either in 'eav_attribute' nor in 'customer_entity_varchar'. Also after cleaning the setup_module table it is still not working.

Comment: Have you enabled you module with `php bin/magento module:enable Magento_CustomerAttribute` command? Do you see `Magento_CustomerAttribute` in `setup_module`?

Comment: That was it I gues :D I now have an entry in my eav_attribute table with the id 136 which is my 'kndnumber'. The Problem now is when I want to create a user it gives me the error message "Kunden nummer" is a required value. I created a custom theme to override the reigister.phtml with my the inputfield which has the same id, but it is given me this error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start and stop setup

```
/**
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup $quoteInstaller */
    $quoteInstaller = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'quote_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

    $quoteInstaller->addAttribute('somename', 'code', ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT, 'length' => 255, 'nullable' => true]);

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: Did that but that also wont work after clearing the 'setup_module' table and running the command it wont work.